# Python - Django - Sum values of a list, too slow

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, sum, django-views

I have a Django project I use to show energy consumptions of a certain time period. I use the following code in order to obtain the data from the database:

```
consumptions = Measurement.objects.filter(idhouse=house)
filtered = consumptions.values_list("cost",flat=True).filter(enddatetimestamp__gt=startdate,enddatetimestamp__lte=enddate)
total = sum(filtered)
```

I obtain a list of 9000 values, but when I sum those values, it takes 3-4 seconds. I don't know why it takes so much time (I have checked queryset is obtained fastly). In addition, I have tested this code:

```
filtered=consumptions.objects.filter(enddatetimestamp__gt=startdatets,enddatetimestamp__lte=enddatets).aggregate(total=Sum('cost'))
total = filtered['total']
```

However, it takes 3-4 seconds too. I've created a python script which does the same job:

```
array = range(9000)
start = datetime.datetime.now()
total = sum(array)
print "Time: \t{}".format(datetime.datetime.now()-start)
```

In this case, the script takes 0.000176 seconds. I don't know where's the difference, taking into account that, in Django's code, I hit the database once, in order to get the consumptions I want. So in theory, it should take the same time.

¿Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you check that the queryset is obtained quickly? Remember that `filtered = consumptions.objects.filter(...)` will not cause the queryset to be evaluated, you need to do something like `results = list(filtered)` to fetch the results.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've realised problem is related with obtaining data, not summing it. However, if I use `filtered=consumptions.objects.filter(enddatetimestamp__gt=startdatets,enddatetimestamp__lte=enddatets).aggregate(total=Sum('cost'))` it still takes 3-4 seconds. Do you know there is any way to make it faster or it's just a database's problem?

Comment: It sounds like a database issue, not a Django issue. It might be possible to speed up e.g. by adding an index.